# Failure when creating Content Runtime

Tags: cloud-automation-manager

When I tried to deploy the Content Runtime it failed with the error:

```
null_resource.singlenode (remote-exec): ERROR: CONFIGURATION ERROR:Specified config file /etc/opscode/pivotal.rb does not exist
null_resource.singlenode (remote-exec): Creating admin user: chef-admin
null_resource.singlenode: Still creating... (8m30s elapsed)
null_resource.singlenode (remote-exec): ERROR: CONFIGURATION ERROR:Specified config file /etc/opscode/pivotal.rb does not exist
Error applying plan:
```

I see this error when I try to create content-runtime using vSphere or Other template. What could be the cause?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From review of the chef logs, you might find a failed chef config, specifically this issue: https://github.com/chef/chef-server/issues/987.

You can clean the chef install (`chef-server-ctl cleanse`), and launch the command line to then successfully complete the install. From CAM perspective, you can resubmit the `other` template create of the content runtime, and the VM will then become usable and known to CAM.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an issue while installing chef. Run the command on the failed vm:

```
~/advanced-content-runtime/verify-installation.sh
```

And check the results.

The command will indicate a failure with chef, but will show you the location of the chef install log:

```
~/advanced-content-runtime/.advanced-runtime-config/chef-install.log
```

Then check the log for pivotal:

```
egrep pivotal ~/advanced-content-runtime/.advanced-runtime-config/chef-install.log
```

On a system where chef installed correctly, the result seen with the commands above are:

```
[2017-11-07T16:44:10-06:00] INFO: Storing updated cookbooks/private-chef/templates/default/pivotal.rb.erb in the cache.
[2017-11-07T16:44:13-06:00] INFO: Processing file[/etc/opscode/pivotal.pem] action create (private-chef::private_keys line 33)
[2017-11-07T16:44:13-06:00] INFO: file[/etc/opscode/pivotal.pem] created file /etc/opscode/pivotal.pem
[2017-11-07T16:44:13-06:00] INFO: file[/etc/opscode/pivotal.pem] updated file contents /etc/opscode/pivotal.pem
[2017-11-07T16:44:13-06:00] INFO: file[/etc/opscode/pivotal.pem] owner changed to 999
[2017-11-07T16:44:13-06:00] INFO: file[/etc/opscode/pivotal.pem] group changed to 0
[2017-11-07T16:44:13-06:00] INFO: file[/etc/opscode/pivotal.pem] mode changed to 600
[2017-11-07T16:47:51-06:00] INFO: Processing template[/etc/opscode/pivotal.rb] action create (private-chef::ctl_config line 32)
[2017-11-07T16:47:51-06:00] INFO: template[/etc/opscode/pivotal.rb] created file /etc/opscode/pivotal.rb
[2017-11-07T16:47:51-06:00] INFO: template[/etc/opscode/pivotal.rb] updated file contents /etc/opscode/pivotal.rb
[2017-11-07T16:47:51-06:00] INFO: template[/etc/opscode/pivotal.rb] owner changed to 0
[2017-11-07T16:47:51-06:00] INFO: template[/etc/opscode/pivotal.rb] group changed to 0
[2017-11-07T16:47:51-06:00] INFO: template[/etc/opscode/pivotal.rb] mode changed to 644
```